# Открытие окна в заданное время C#

Tags: c#

Приветствую.

Есть вопросик, по поводу открытия окна в заданное время. К примеру, в 12:00:05 нужно открыть форму с напоминалкой покормить кота.

В принципе, я понял что нужно задать таймеру время, в которое он будет срабатывать, но вот что делать дальше не очень понимаю. Как показать таймеру, что он должен работать не с тиками, а с заданным временем?

Если можно, с примером.

Заранее благодарю всех.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А документацию почитать?

```
using System.Threading;

var timer = new Timer(
    _ => OpenWindow, null,
    new DateTime(2014, 5, 18, 12, 0, 5) - DateTime.Now,
    TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(-1));

void OpenWindow()
{
    // marshal to UI thread
}
```

И никакого поллинга, прости господи.

Comment: 2014, 5, 18, сие есть дата. Без неё не поедет, как я понимаю. А эвридей? 

выкрутился так 

<pre><code>

                int hr = 16;
                int min = 49;
                int sec = 00;
                if ((hr >= System.DateTime.Now.Hour) && (min >= System.DateTime.Now.Minute) && (sec >= System.DateTime.Now.Second))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Аларм, кот голодный");
                }
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);

    </code></pre>

Comment: @VaLenOK007: Ну, возьмите значения года, месяца и дня из `DateTime.Now`.

Comment: Чтож, спасибо за помощь)

Comment: @VaLenOK007: пожалуйста!

Answer (score 0):

Нужно каждую секунду получать текущее время, и если оно равно какому-то значению, показывать окно.

Comment: Это понятно. Мне не ясно как заставить таймер именно сравнивать. То, что нужно задать часы и минуты в переменные понятно, но как именно это реализовать - не очень понимаю